# Is it possible to use non-global variables in function?

Tags: javascript

I've really looked all over for this and haven't found an answer that really explained this well...

I know how to access a global variable from within a function.

```
myGlobalVariable = [];
function myFunction() {
  myGlobalVariable.push("somedata");
}
```

Now how do I access a variable one step up on the scope chain if it isn't global?

```
myGlobalVariable = [];

function myFunction() {

  var notGlobalVariable = "somedata";

  var myOtherFunction = function() {
    myGlobalVariable.push(notGlobalVariable); // This is what I'd like to be able to do.
  }

}
```

I know I could do something like

```
var notGlobalVariable = "somedata";

var myOtherFunction = function(arg) {
  myGlobalVariable.push(arg);
}

myOtherFunction(notGlobalVariable);
```

But calling the function that way only works if I have the value of `notGlobalVariable` readily available. I'd like do be able to globally call the function and have it always use the value originally held by `notGlobalVariable` without having to pass that value in.

**Edit**
Alright, I kinda jumped the gun on this one.  I though I was having a big variable scope issue, but apparently my issue was that in my specific code I was using the variable name `arguments` in place of `notGlobalVariable`, and as I should have known, `arguments` is shadowed and refers to the arguments passed in.  I changed the name to `args` and it works fine.  Sorry!

Comment: What's the issue? Your example works perfectly.

Comment: Your example should work.  Perhaps you're only assigning `myOtherFunction` and not calling `myOtherFunction` with `myOtherFunction()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N4kfY/1/ - Works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does that automatically by creating closures.

- Every function creates its own scope.
- Scopes are nested, since functions can be defined within functions.
- Every new nested scope (*"function"*) can see all the variables that were defined in any parent scope *at the point of its (i.e that new function's) creation*. This is called a closure.
- Every variable from any parent scope is "by reference" - child scopes (*"functions"*) always see their current values.
- The point in time when the function *runs* does not matter, only the point in time when it was declared (see first example).
- The scope where a function *runs in* does not matter, only the scope a function was *defined in* (see second example).

Here

```
var myGlobalVariable = [];

// define function => creates closure #1
function myFunction() {
  var notGlobalVariable = "somedata";

  // define function => creates closure #2
  var myOtherFunction = function() {
    myGlobalVariable.push(notGlobalVariable);
  }

  // execute function
  myOtherFunction();
}

myFunction();  // myGlobalVariable will be ["somedata"]
```

you create two scopes:

1. `myFunction` can see `myGlobalVariable`
2. the anonymous function stored in `myOtherFunction` can see `myGlobalVariable` and `notGlobalVariable`.

Now assume a small change:

```
var myGlobalVariable = [];

// define function => creates closure #1
function myFunction(callback) {
  var notGlobalVariable = "somedata";

  // define function => creates closure #2
  var myOtherFunction = function() {
    myGlobalVariable.push(callback());
  }

  // execute function
  myOtherFunction();
}

// define function => creates closure #3
function foo() {
  var thisIsPrivate = "really";

  // define function => creates closure #4
  return function () {
    return thisIsPrivate;
  }
}

myFunction(foo());  // myGlobalVariable will be ["really"]
```

You see that the `callback` function has access to `thisIsPrivate` because it was *defined* in the right scope, even though the scope it is *executed in* cannot see the variable.

Likewise the `callback` function will not be able to see `notGlobalVariable`, even though that variable is visible in the scope where the callback is executed.

Note that you *always* must use `var` on any variable you define. Otherwise variables will be silently global which can and will lead to hard to fix bugs in your program.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation of scopes and closures. I would give +100 if I could. Now I'm embarrassed with my laconic answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - in javascript everything is possible - here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AZ2Rv/

```
myGlobalVariable = [];

function myFunction() {

  var notGlobalVariable = "somedata";

  // The following assigns a function to a variable
  var myOtherFunction = function() {
    myGlobalVariable.push(notGlobalVariable);
  }

  // The following line was missing in the code in the question so the function
  // was never called and `notGlobalVariable` wasn't pushed into `myGlobalVariable`
  myOtherFunction();
}

// And just to test if it works as expected
myFunction();
alert(myGlobalVariable[0]);
```

The problem of the OP laid actually in the code he didn't posted, but this sample code answers the original question - closures still work in javascript as expected.

Comment: I don't know man, but it looks exactly as what OP already had (except the added function call)

Comment: And this missing call was exactly what caused `notGlobalVariable` to not be pushed into `myGlobalVariable`...

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I've looked at revisions of question and in none of the 2 version of question and name `arguments` has been used. I was posting my answer basing on the original question. Why do you blame me for not being a mind-reader? The question still is `Is it possible to use non-global variables in function?`. Ain't my post an answer for this question?

Comment: My point is that there was no issue to fix since the beginning, except the lacking (supposedly implicit) function call, in which case the question would most likely receive close votes for being non-repro than answers.

Answer (score 1):

You do have access to `notGlobalVariable` inside of `myOtherFunction`.  However you're only assigning `myOtherFunction` and never invoking it.  Note that you'll have to invoke `myOtherFunction` inside of `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction() {

  var notGlobalVariable = "somedata";

  var myOtherFunction = function() {
    myGlobalVariable.push(notGlobalVariable); // This is what I'd like to be able to do.
  }
  //Invoke myOtherFunction()
  myOtherFunction()

}
```

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo you received downvotes either because you didn't explain your answer or because people retaliated to your comments.  They came of as a bit mean-spirited IMO...even if you didn't intend them to be.